# Magento 2 : Extension attributes & Eav Attributes

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes, eav-attributes

Few question based on extension attributes & eav attributes.
Answers to this question will clear the concept of this topic.

1. What are extension & eav attributes in magento ?
2. What is the purpose of these attributes ?
3. What is the difference between these two ?
4. What are the examples of these in magento database ?
5. How to create & identify these attributes ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html :)